# Are REML estimators of variance-covariance parameters consistent?

Tags: consistency, reml

I am trying to locate some reference papers about consistency of REML estimators in linear mixed effects models. My understanding is that in linear model scenario, REML will produce the exact same estimator for residual variance as OLS, thus it is unbiased. However, I wonder if REML estimators are consistent in general mixed effect models.